# TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to NodeJS and I'm trying to make a backend API for a car rental agency. I have defined the type of 'name' as string and also I'm not passing an empty string in the request then too why is it showing this error? I'm searching for the solution since days but cannot find the answer anywhere on the internet. I read somewhere the older version of mongoose had a bug so I tried after updating it then too the error is not going and also tried updating to the latest NodeJS version.

Here is my code,

index.js

```
let express = require('express');

let app = express();

let mongoose = require('mongoose');

var port = process.env.PORT || 8081

let bodyparser = require('body-parser');

const { urlencoded } = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded(
    {
       extended: true 
    }))

app.use(bodyparser.json());

var apiRoutes = require('./routes');
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);


const dbPath = "mongodb://localhost/carrentalagencypractice"
const options = {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true}
const mongo = mongoose.connect(dbPath,options)

mongo.then(()=>{
    console.log('Connected to mongodb')
} ,error=> {console.log(error,'error')})


app.use('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Welcome to Car Rental Agency')
});


app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log('Running on port '+port)
});
```

routes.js

```
let router = require('express').Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.json({
       status: 'API works',
       message: 'Welcome to Car Rental Agency services'
   })
})


var carController = require('./carController')
var userController = require('./userController')

router.route('/car').get(carController.index).post(carController.add)
router.route('/user').get(userController.index).post(userController.add)

router.route('/car/car_id').get(carController.view).patch(carController.update).put(carController.update).delete(carController.delete)
router.route('/user/user_id').get(userController.index).patch(userController.update).put(userController.update).delete(userController.delete)

module.exports = router
```

carModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var carSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    brand:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    price:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    capacity:{
        type: String,
        required:true
    }
});


var Car = module.exports = mongoose.model('car',carSchema);

module.exports.get = function(callback, limit){
    Car.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

userModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    phone:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    address:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})


var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema)

module.exports.get = function(callback, limit){
    User.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

userController.js

```
User = require("./userModel");


exports.index = function(req, res){
    User.get(function(err, user){
    if(err)
    res.send(err)

    res.json({
        status: "Got all user details successfully",
        message: user
    })
})
}

exports.add = function(req, res){
User.add(function(err, user){
    var user = new User()

    if(err)
    res.send(err)

    user.name = req.body.name ? req.body.name : user.name;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.address = req.body.address;
    user.phone = req.body.phone;

    res.json({
        status: "User details are successfully added",
        message: user
    })
})
}


exports.view = function(req, res){
    User.findByID(req.params.user_id, function(err, user){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        res.json({
            status: "Successfully retreived user details",
            message: user
        })
    })
}

exports.update = function(req, res){
    User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        user.name = req.body.name? req.body.name: user.name;
        user.email = req.body.email;
        user.address = req.body.address;
        user.phone = req.body.phone;

        user.save(function(req, res){
            if(err)
            res.send(err)
    
            res.json({
                status: "User details updated successfully",
                message: user
            })
        })
    }
    )
}


exports.delete = function(req, res){
    User.deleteOne(req.params.user_id, function(err, user){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)
        
        res.json({
            status: "success",
            message: "The user account has been deleted"
        })
    })
}
```

carController.js

```
Car = require('./carModel');


exports.index = function(req, res){
                    
    Car.get(function(err, car){
        if(err)
        res.json({
            status: "error",
            message: err
        })

        res.json({
            status: "successfull",
            message: "Car details succesfully retreived",
            data: car
        })
    });
}


exports.add = function(req, res){
    var car = new Car();
    car.name = res.body.name ? req.body.name : car.name;
    car.brand = res.body.brand;
    car.price = res.body.price;
    car.capacity = res.body.capacity;


    car.save(function(err){
        if(err)
        res.json(err);
        console.log

        res.json({
            status: "successfull",
            message: "Successfully add new car details"
        })

    })

}


exports.view = function(req, res){
    Car.findById(req.params.car_id, function(err, car){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        res.json({
            status: "Car details",
            message: car
        })
    })

}


exports.update = function(req, res){
    Car.findById(req.params.car_id, function(err, car){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        car.name = req.body.name? req.body.name: car.name;
        car.price = req.body.price;
        car.brand = req.body.brand;
        car.capacity = req.body.capacity;

        car.save(function(err){

            if(err)
            res.send(err)

            res.json({
                status:"Car details updated successfully",
                message: car
            })

        })
    })
}


exports.delete = function(req, res){
    Car.deleteOne({
        _id: car_id
    }, function(err, contact){
        if(err)
        res.send(err)

        res.json({
            status: "success",
            message:"Car ad deleted"
        })
    }
    )
}
```

[POSTMAN request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZHid.png)

It throws the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at exports.add (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\carController.js:26:25)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
    at next (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:14)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
    at router (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Work\NodeJS Practice\Car Rental Agency (Practice)\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In carController.js it should be,

```js
exports.add = function(req, res){
    var car = new Car();
    car.name = req.body.name ? req.body.name : car.name;
    car.brand = req.body.brand;
    car.price = req.body.price;
    car.capacity = req.body.capacity;
```

Mainly I have replaced res with req, because you are accessing the response body and which is undefined and you cannot access the name property on undefined.

Comment: I have replaced res with req in the last four lines, I have explained in the answer please check it once again.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have any other issues

Answer (score 1):

In carController.js it should be,

line number 26
your code

```
car.name = res.body.name ? req.body.name : car.name;
```

correct code

```
car.name = req.body.name ? req.body.name : car.name;
```